# Running a for loop for higher number of iterations in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, tuples

I have written a piece of code which I am trying to run in my local machine of 8GB ram.

```
import numpy as np

tasks = ['A','B','C','D']
tasks_pass_prob = [0.7,0.1,0.5,0.3]
task_probs = tuple(zip(tasks,tasks_pass_prob))
N = 1000000 
n = 1
results_dict = {}

for _ in range(N):
    for t,p in task_probs:
        res = np.random.binomial(n,p,N)
        results_dict[t]=res
```

For smaller values of `N` code is running but with a higher value of `N` the machine gets hung. Is a better way to restructure my for loop to run the code ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your code is not hanging but your processes are so big that it's taking a long time to run...
It is not the issue of RAM...

And why did you use `for _ in range(N)`?

I suggest you write it like this:

```py
import numpy as np

tasks = ['A','B','C','D']
tasks_pass_prob = [0.7,0.1,0.5,0.3]
task_probs = tuple(zip(tasks,tasks_pass_prob))
N = 1000000
n = 1
results_dict = {}

# for _ in range(N):
for t, p in task_probs:
    res = np.random.binomial(n, p, N)
    results_dict[t] = res
    print(f"{res=}, {results_dict=}")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I can achieve the same thing by simply removing the first loop like so...

```
import numpy as np

tasks = ['A','B','C','D']
tasks_pass_prob = [0.7,0.1,0.5,0.3]
task_probs = tuple(zip(tasks,tasks_pass_prob))
N = 1000000
n = 1
results_dict = {}

for t,p in task_probs:
    res = np.random.binomial(n,p,N)
    results_dict[t]=res
```